# How can I block popunders?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, blocking

I am wondering if there are any browser addons which allow me to block annoying popunders?

Comment: Any particular Browser?

Comment: Chrome Browser's default popup blocker works well..http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typical pop-up blocker will block them. (Despite the name, a "pop-under" is not really any different from a "pop-up", except that it deliberately appears without taking focus so as to appear "under" your browser window.) Most (all?) the modern browsers have built-in ones these days -- I know for sure that IE, Firefox, and Chrome do, and I'd be surprised if Safari and Opera did not.

The problem is that often these things (pop-ups/-unders) will appear in response to you clicking on a link, which pop-up blockers will often allow through because it appears that you intended to open it. (Although the blockers are getting more and more strict about just blocking everything unless and until you specifically tell them to let it through.)

Comment: Opera has an excellent pop-up (and pop-under, pop-next-to, pop-around, pop-overlay, pop-goes-the-world, etc.) blocker.

Comment: what about pop goes the weasel blocking? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, install the "[Poper Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkkbcggnhapdmkeljlodobbkopceiche)" extension. It's the first dedicated pop-under killer out there!